# What's the proper way to center horizontally within a div?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to HTML/CSS so feel free to correct any other mistakes that I've (probably) made. Here's my HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/luxurymode/PrjJ3/3/

All I want to do is to center horizontally the UL within that "navbar". What's the correct way do it?

EDIT: I accidentally posted the wrong fiddle. It's correct now...

Comment: There are many ways to achieve the effect. What do "proper" and "correct" mean to you?

Comment: a better way to have your li elements to be in the same line would be to add them display: inline, remove float: left, and remove display: block from links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way is

```css
#topbar ul {
    width: /* exact width of the ul */;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/PrjJ3/8/)

Another way is

```css
#topbar {
    text-align: center;
}

#topbar ul {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

but `inline-block` isn't 100% x-browser proof.

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/PrjJ3/7/)

Comment: What if they ul width can be dynamic? I know many cases where I cannot hard code in a width or a menu like this.

Comment: Thanks! And how about vertically? Once I added the margin 0 auto, the vertical centering seems to have gone away. http://jsfiddle.net/luxurymode/PrjJ3/9/

Comment: Thumbs up for providing both ways paislee.

Comment: @LuxuryMode for some reason the `ul` has a default margin of 16px.. To get it back use `margin: 16px auto;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you will always know the value of your ul, then use the examples from the first couple answers. If you do not know the what the width will be, you must use a slightly different method. Change your `float:left;` on your li's to `display:inline;` and then add `text-align:center;` to your ul.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to give the list a width and set the margin to 0 auto:

```
#topbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;  
    margin:0 auto;   
    width:300px  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
For browser compatibility (IE & FF) with inline-block, use:

```
display:-moz-inline-stack;
display:inline-block;
zoom:1;
*display:inline;
```

So in #nav li, remove float: left and make it:

```
#nav li {
    display:-moz-inline-stack;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    *display:inline;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba( 255, 255,255, 0.1);
}
```

Then to center you Nav

```
#nav {
    padding: .5em;
    height: 55px;  
    width: 650px;
    background-color: #325A8C;
    text-align: center;

}
```